# Button calling different servlet code in html form

Tags: servlets

I am bit new to Java web programming 
I have two buttons(Test connection and Execute) in an html form and the form action is a servlet. How can I differentiate the action in the servlet based on which button is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML:

```
<input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='Test connection' />
<input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='execute' />
```

In the servlet:

```
String clickedButtonValue = request.getParameter("submitButton");
if("Test connection".equals(clickedButtonValue))
{
 ...
}
else if("execute".equals(clickedButtonValue))
{
 ...
}
else ...
```

The reason this works: With both submit buttons sharing the same `name` attribute, the browser will only send the `value` of the one that was clicked.